# How to save a COM control's data to a existint excel file?

Tags: excel, com, atl

Here's the thing.

I develop a COM control using ATL in VS2015, and implement the IPersistStorage and IPersistStreamInit interface(through template in ATL), I register the control and Open a existing excel file ,and Add controls via COM add-ins.

My Question : How to save the control's data to the existing excel file. When I open the file next time , the data saved in control last time can present.

plus:
first, my excel file is common file storing data;
second, I can not find the container application(namely excel file)'s store interface！
third, excel file as a compound document，Whether the IStorage interface is implemented？if not,any other Interface I can use?

Comment: I am curious that excel file wheather belong to compound document? if yes, where is it root storage,,MSDN says word and excel all use compound documents as their storage structure, Is the excel file and its compound document separate?

Comment: No one knows about it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.